# Why sequelize.findOne() is not returning the result while I can see the result is in my DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I am trying to save some data to my database, but I have a condition, if the data is already exist don't insert it again.

I created couple functions for this task. I can insert data into my database without any problem. But once I start adding this existing data checking condition, it looks like the findOne() function is always returning null even though I just add the data into DB.

the highest level code to run insert into database, the saveInvoice(i) is working:

```
if (!this.checkInvoic(i)) {
  this.saveInvoice(i)
 }
```

The code to check if invoice data already exist, the result should be something, but it is null:

```
checkInvoic(invoice) {
  return this.checkSingleInvoice(invoice.team_id, 
    invoice.invoice_number)
            .then((result) => {    // this result should be something.
                if (result !== undefined) {
                return resolve(true);
            } else {
                return resolve(false);
            }
            })
    }
```

These are the functions dealing with sequelize:

```
create(invoice) {
        return this.invoicesModel.create(invoice);
    }

checkSingleInvoice(team_id, invoice_id) {
        return this.invoicesModel.findOne({
            where: {
                invoice_id,
                team_id,
            }
        })
    }
```

I am expecting when I provide invoice.team_id and invoice.invoice_id into checkSingleInvoice() function it will return the result which is existing in DB, and return true in checkInvoice() function.
But when I ran it, the result in the line that I have a comment on, returned null. I am just wondering why?  Is that something I did wrong in Promise or Sequelize?

Comment: Could you please provide the field names for Invoice model?

Comment: @Sergii Vorobei   const InvoicesModel = connection.define('invoices', {
        invoice_id:{
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequalize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },

        team_id:{
            type: Sequalize.UUID,
            allowNull: false,
        },

        invoice_number:{
            type: Sequalize.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
        },

Comment: When you call `this.checkSingleInvoice` you pass `invoice.invoice_number` but inside of the function in the `findOne`, you use it as `invoice_id`. Can this be the root cause considering these are different fields?

Comment: @Sergii Vorobei data model should not be a problem, since I can insert the data into database whichout problem. The problem is I can find the data in database, even it is right there.

Comment: @@Sergii Vorobei Yes, it is exactly the root cause. I am a idiot. Thank you sir.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that `checkInvoic` (sic) returns a `Promise`, but your conditional check doesn't account for this.

There are two possible fixes:

**1) Using `await`**

```js
if (await !this.checkInvoic(i)) {
  this.saveInvoice(i)
}
```

**2) Using `then`:**

```js
this.checkInvoic(i).then(exists => {
  if (!exists) return this.saveInvoice()
}
```